# What does "come up with" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Waits muttered the joke on Norman Lear’s television show Fernwood 2
>   Night in 1977, but he didn’t come up with it.

I searched the phrase [come up with](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-up-with) in Longman Dictionary, it means:

- to think of an idea
- to produce an amount of money

I know the first meaning is better but I still cannot understand the meaning of the sentence above.

So, could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> Once, when asked about his drinking, the musician Tom Waits famously
>   muttered, “I’d rather have a bottle in front of me than a frontal
>   lobotomy.” He appeared to be hammered when he said it. Oh, and he was
>   on national television.**Waits muttered the joke** on Norman Lear’s
>   television show Fernwood 2 Night in 1977, but he
>   **didn’t come up with it**. Nobody knows where the joke originated, and if you try to find out online, you’ll lose yourself down a rabbit
>   hole of theories. Some have credited the joke to the writer Dorothy
>   Parker, others to comedian Steve Allen. Waits himself claimed he
>   didn’t remember where he first heard it. He also admitted that the
>   joke wasn’t his.

Comment: You already answered your question with the first meaning you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first meaning perfectly fits, as you've already deducted.

> Waits muttered the joke on Norman Lear’s television show Fernwood 2 Night in 1977, but he didn’t come up with it.

This simply means that even though the joke in question was mentioned on the show by Waits, it was not his own creation, i.e., Waits did not think of the joke, someone else did. He just used it in the show.